# Basic shared_count variant

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

Since I need a special refcounting mechanism in a project (which does not always expose the pointer), I would like to implement my object handling on top of basic refcounting.

*libstdc++* and *libc++* both use a class `std::__shared_count` for the basic (type unspecific) ref counting.
When looking into *boost*, they also have a `boost::detail::shared_count` class.

I would now base my attempt on `boost::detail::shared_count`, but am hesitant, because it has already been changed in past *boost* versions. Is there another basic ref counting mechanism available for usage?

Comment: What do you mean by not exposing the pointer? Given a type you can always form a pointer to that type. And there are several ways to implement ref-counting: intrusive (through a base-class), non-intrusive (think `shared_ptr`) and unless you want it to be thread-safe it is not that hard to implement.

Comment: `shared_count` maintains _two_ counts, because it needs to support a `weak_ptr` count too, do you need two counts? If not, `shared_count` may not be a good choice.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That is, what I am currently analyzing.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Turns out I need weak_ptr capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, you'll have the `use_count`member function if you need to explicitly know the count, and the custom deleter automatically acts as a callback when the count hits 0.

The real advantage with this technique is that it is portable and probably well tested, not to mention that the whole mess of counter heap allocation managment and thread synchronisation is already done.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need weak pointers, there's no need to bolt reference-counting onto your reference-counting.

Try [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) first.
(You will need to implement `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release`.)

Otherwise, just use a custom deleter and you are home free.

```
struct my_delete {
    void operator()(MyClass* p) const {p->Release();}
};
```